# STS Insight server and file location

Tags: spring, spring-roo

I am using Spring roo and STS Insight server. I want to create a javascripts folder to add my javascript files and link them in my JSP. however, I don't know where to put the javascript files because, my JSP never can find it.

More interestingly, the dojo.js is located with no fuss. I looked in my sts directory. It appears insight.war could be housing the dojo.js. but I still can't figure out how the path is setup.

resources/dojo/dojo.js is located. 
in file system, we have insight.war/dojo/dojo/dojo.js. So clearly, resources is pointed to insight.war/dojo/dojo.js. Where is this configuration? I want to change it, Preferably best load it from within my application.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your files (images, css, javascript ...) in `src\main\webapp`

include a css like

```
<style type="text/css">
   @import "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/your_dir_in_src_main_webapp/your_css.css";
</style>
```

include a js like

if you js contains jsp tag then

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
<%@ include file="/your_dir_in_src_main_webapp/your_js.js" %>
 </script>
```

if you js doesnt contant jsp tag than

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/your_dir_in_src_main_webapp/your_js.js"></script>
```